# OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications - where do I get a redirect_uri

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-apps, google-cloud-platform

I'm working through the instructions to use OAuth2 to get access to Gmail in an installed (Windows) application, on the page https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp. It all seems straightforward until I get to the part about "making a token request". One of the parameters to the POST I have to do is redirect_uri, which it says is "The redirect URI you obtained from the Developers Console."

I have obtained my ClientID and ClientSecret from the Developers Console, but can't see anywhere that I get a redirect_uri from it.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: redirect URI for an installed application (Native client on the dev console) is urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob.  However you shouldn't really need it, I guess it depends on the client library you are using.

Comment: That's the redirect_uri for the initial authentication request, sent to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth. I'm OK with that one. 

My question is about the next transaction, under the heading "Handling the response and making a token request" in that page. That appears to be a different redirect_uri, and it's not clear how to get it.

Comment: Want to share some code what step are you on do you have the authentication code?

Comment: Yes I have the authorization code (as Google calls it), copied in from a browser window that I display to get the user's authorization. I don't see how my code to do that will help. I just need help understanding the next transaction I need to do, specifically the parameter redirect_uri, which the page describes as "The redirect URI you obtained from the Developers Console.". This is the transaction that posts to the /oauth2/v4/token endpoint, with parameters code, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, and grant_type.

Comment: I have a post on it.  see if this helps http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/  I tried to make it more simple then googles example

Comment: Thank you Linda that is extremely helpful. So it appears the redirect_uri in the 2nd transaction I'm wondering about is the same as the one in the first transaction that I used to get the authorization code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102285/discussion-between-dan-cooperstock-and-daimto).

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is baslicy a three or four step process

Step one is just getting the authentication code.  this link can be placed in any browser window its a HTTP GET

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code

Once the user has accepted access you will be given an authentication code.

That code is sent back to the server to get a refresh token and the first access token.  this is a HTTP POST.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The response will be something like this

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

The access token will only work for one hour and it will expire after that you will need to use the refresh token to get a new access token.

This is also a HTTP Post

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

response

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```

code has been ripped from my tutorial [Google 3 legged oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/) it has more explanation than this.