# how to get json reply with token details in google oauth back to my app. What should be the redirect uri?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, google-oauth

Say, I have set my app url and it can be accessed like :

> example://com.example.app

(worked fine and was able to open using safari in ios simulator).

And I set my redirect_uri (google oauth) as example://com.example.app in order to get a json with the access_token details.

Is it a correct way to approach?

If I run my app in a simulator it says, bad request : 400.

Kindly let me know how I can get the json back to my app using httpwebrequest/response methods, if at all it is possible!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. 
I just set the redirect_uri to : urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
and i am getting the json back!
Really good answer (it saved my day) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35139800/6449542